# POCO proxy not able to automatically set a relationship

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

One of the requieremets for change tracking proxies is that a navigation property that represents the "many" end of a relationship must return a type that implements `ICollection`.

Change tracking proxies also provide classes with **automatic relationship fix-up**. For example, when `someEmployee.Addresses.Add(address);` is executed, proxy automatically sets `address.EmployeeID` to value of `100` and also assigns `someEmployee` instance to a navigation property `address.Employee`:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public virtual int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }

Employee someEmployee = ...;
Address address = ...;

Console.WriteLine(someEmployee.EmployeeID); // 100
Console.WriteLine(address.EmployeeID); // 20

someEmployee.Addresses.Add(address);

Console.WriteLine(address.EmployeeID); // 100
Console.WriteLine(address.Employee.EmployeeID); // 100
```

But if we change the definition of Employee class, then for some reason proxy isn't able to automatically fix-up the relationship:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        private List<Address> _addresses = new List<Address>();

        public virtual int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses 
        {
            get { return _addresses; }
            set { _addresses = value.ToList(); }
        }
    }

Console.WriteLine(someEmployee.EmployeeID); // 100
Console.WriteLine(address.EmployeeID); // 20

someEmployee.Addresses.Add(address);

Console.WriteLine(address.EmployeeID); // 20
Console.WriteLine(address.Employee.EmployeeID); // 20
```

Navigation property `Employee.Addresses` does return a type that implements `ICollection`  ( `List<T>` ), so why isn't proxy able to fix-up the relationship?

Thank you

**EDIT**

**It is because the proxy itself doesn't fixup the relation. It replaces your instantiated collections with its own but once you call value.ToList() you are throwing away its implementation with fixup logic.**

But if calling `value.ToList()` is the reason why automatic relationship fix-up doesn't work, then  removing the `setter` method should enable automatic relationship fix-up, but it doesn't:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        private List<Address> _addresses = new List<Address>();

        public virtual int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses 
        {
            get { return _addresses; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the proxy itself doesn't fixup the relation. It replaces your instantiated collections with its own but once you call `value.ToList()` you are throwing away its implementation with fixup logic. Use this instead and it should work as expected:

```
public class Employee
{
    public ICollection<Address> addresses = new List<Address>(); 

    public virtual int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return addresses; } 
        set { addresses = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Reason why your suggestion didn't work is because one of the properties wasn't marked virtual. Anyhow, are you sure reason why automatic relationship fix-up doesn't work is due to calling value.List()? Please see my edit

Comment: Won't bother you again, but just in case you find the time ... could you see my edit?

Comment: No. Properties must have setter to make them work in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
public class Employee {
    private ICollection<Address> _addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

    public virtual int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses {
        get { return _addresses ?? (_addresses = new HashSet<Address>()); }
        protected set { _addresses = value; }
    }
}
```

The advantage is that the Addresses collection in the POCO class will also be automatically instantiated when you create your entity with `new` (rather than using the [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487204.aspx) or [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.create%28VS.103%29.aspx) methods) for use in situations where proxies are undesirable (e.g. serialization).

Another change is that the ICollection is implemented as a HashSet<> instead of a List<>, ensuring uniqueness.